# number of zeros of a complex polynomial's leading term

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n+1}+...$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Prove that in a disc of sufficiently large radius, $p(z)$ and $r(z)=a_n z^n$ have the same number of zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of zeros of $p$ is finite, equal to the degree. Consider a disc of radius the largest modulus of a root, plus an epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

hint:You can use Rouche's Theorem.